# Working code with line duplication. Any help solving this logical issue?

Tags: jquery

With a lot of trial and error, and without understanding about the guts of it, I've made this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7T4w4/24/

```
$("#experience-left-details").on('click', '.see-map, .see-gallery', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle(
        function(){
            $(".media-container, .swiper-container").toggleClass('hide');
            mySwiper.resizeFix(true);
            mySwiper.reInit(true);    
        }
    );
    $("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle();
});
```

Is there a way to remake this code, by keeping the functionality (obviously), without repeating this line:

```
$("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle();
```

Comment: You want to remove the `fadeToggle()` function? Any particular reason?

Comment: @TomWalters I'm calling it twice, and perhaps it's better if I just called once.

Comment: @MEM you need to call it twice if you want the frame to fade back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/p8akD/)

I feel you on calling the same method twice in a row, here is how I would go about cleaning it up:

```
// store the jquery object for later use, 
// instead of recreating over and over
var $eld = $("#experience-left-details"); 

$eld.on('click', '.see-map, .see-gallery', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // use fadeOut its more clear as to what you are doing
    $eld.fadeOut(
        function(){
            $(".media-container, .swiper-container").toggleClass('hide');
            mySwiper.resizeFix(true);
            mySwiper.reInit(true);    
        }
    // chain on fadeIn for after fadeOut is done
    ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Indeed it seems to do the same. I still have an issue, when I click "see map" then resize the window, then click "see gallery". I though it was your demo, but I guess it's on the original code posted on the question. :)

Comment: I will accept your answer, because you did answered. If, however, you happen to know how to solve the issue, please update your answer. I've been trying this for at least 7 hours. :s

Comment: Regarding the issue, I've duplicated again. :( And it still isn't perfect. argghh!!! :s http://jsfiddle.net/x29Xk/

Comment: Hey, submit a new question detailing **exactly** the way this is supposed to work and the resize issue, and mention me in the comments section. I will come help you.

Comment: Just created - it tooked some time to sum it all up. Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412741/how-to-implement-a-fade-effect-or-any-other-effect-on-toggle