# How to implement a fade effect (or any other effect) on toggle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, swiper.js

Here's how the toggle should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/uVaQ3/

```
$("#experience-left-details").on('click', '.see-map, .see-gallery', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".media-container, .swiper-container").toggleClass('hide');
    mySwiper.resizeFix(true);
    mySwiper.reInit(true);

});
```

**GOAL**

**Add a fade in or any other effect on this.**

TRY 1)

So I've tried to apply the effect on the container:
http://jsfiddle.net/x29Xk/

```
$("#experience-left-details").on('click', '.see-map, .see-gallery', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle();
    $(".media-container, .swiper-container").toggleClass('hide');
    mySwiper.resizeFix(true);
    mySwiper.reInit(true);
    $("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle();
});
```

**Issue:** it blinks, doesn't fade.

TRY 2)

http://jsfiddle.net/7T4w4/24/

```
$("#experience-left-details").on('click', '.see-map, .see-gallery', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle(
        function(){
            $(".media-container, .swiper-container").toggleClass('hide');
            mySwiper.resizeFix(true);
            mySwiper.reInit(true);    
        }
    );
    $("#experience-left-details").fadeToggle();
});
```

Fixed the blink, but...
**Issue:** If you click "see map" then resize the window, then click "see gallery" you will see that the gallery is **NOT** properly rendered.

Any help please? The intended end result is to use a slide effect, not fade, but, if one works, I suppose any other will too.

Comment: @Fresheyeball - Invoking more knowledgeable ppl then me. :)

Comment: Hey buddy, give me a few to get back to my desk and I will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/p8akD/1/)

The problem you are encountering is that you are asking `Swiper` to recalculate its size at a moment when its not visible, and therefore has no size. So we need to be calling `resizeFix` at a moment when the element is visible. To do this wait `16ms` (or one frame) of the fadeIn animation to call `resizeFix`, that way its the minimum partially visible, and `Swiper` can determine its new size.

```
var $eld = $("#experience-left-details");
$eld.on('click', '.see-map, .see-gallery', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $eld.fadeOut(
        function(){
            $(".media-container, .swiper-container").toggleClass('hide');
            // wait one frame to resize
            setTimeout(function(){
                mySwiper.reInit(true);
                mySwiper.resizeFix(true);            
            }, 16);
        }
    ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: So, if I change the animation, I should see what is the "one frame" for that animation, so that, it executes resize only when that animation is finished (and consequently) the element has a size to be fixed?

Comment: one frame is always 16ms

Comment: Just seen your demo. It just blinks for a fraction... and it seems that, for that fraction of time, the map appears... I will try to play with it. But, if that can't be solved, I believe it's a minor issue to leave with. :) ps- My heyballs are anything but fresh after this. :)